# inherit from rounded button

Tags: iphone, uibutton

i inherit from UIButton but i found a problem how to initialize it to an UIButtonRoundedRect 
i wrote this to initialize my heritated button

```
-(id)initWithEvent:(NSDictionary*)myEvent{


 self=[super init];

 self.event=myEvent;//if i use what Erdemus said event is not allocated

 return self;
}
```

the type of button have a readonly property so i can't change it after been initialized
thank you for help.

Comment: Sorry, that's a problem. What are you doing with event after?

Comment: event is an NSDictionary object which contains an information that i will use after the "click event" on the button created.

Answer (score 0):

The answer of Erdemus was not the convenient one , because with his answer self is casted to an UIButton object so objective-c doesn't recognize the attributes of my class.
there is another suggestion?